# How to add multiple values to the same key in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, elementtree

I've got a situation where I am trying to use a Dictionary in Python to keep track of an ID and a CLASSNAME.  I am using a dictionary because I need to know what ID the CLASSNAME belongs to.  However, although I only have one ID, I can have multiple CLASSNAME(S).  Here is a snippet of what I am doing in my code.  Because of the way I am adding the key:value to the dictionary, I only get the last value for that key instead of all of the values.

```
elementTree = self.param2
audio = {}

if elementTree.find('./connections') is None:
    return
else:
    for connection_element in elementTree.findall('.//connections/connection'):
        # Get the type for this connection.
        controlType = connection_element.find('type')
        # Get the id for this connection.
        connectionID = connection_element.find('id')
        if controlType is not None and str(controlType.text) == '6':
            # Now find all of the classname(s) in this specific connection element.
            for class_name in connection_element.findall('classes/class/classname'):
                audio[connectionID.text] = class_name.text
    return audio
```

Here is an example of the data the above function is trying to parse:

```
    <connection>
        <id>3002</id>
        <type>6</type>
        <classes>
            <class>
                <classname>DIGITAL_COAX</classname>
            </class>
            <class>
                <classname>DIGITAL_OPTICAL</classname>
            </class>
            <class>
                <classname>STEREO</classname>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </connection>
```

What I am currently getting back is the 3002:STEREO.  3002 is the ID and STEREO is the CLASSNAME.  What I would like to get back is something like the following:

```
3002:DIGITAL_COAX
3002:DIGITAL_OPTICAL
3002:STEREO
```

How can I properly use the Dictionary to make sure I can assign multiple values to the same key?

Comment: You can only have one value per key in a dictionary; however, note that that one value could be a container of some kind (e.g. another dictionary or a list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) appending the values to a list:

```
from collections  import defaultdict

audio = defaultdict(list)

if elementTree.find('./connections') is None:
    return
else:
    for connection_element in elementTree.findall('.//connections/connection'):
        # Get the type for this connection.
        controlType = connection_element.find('type')
        # Get the id for this connection.
        connectionID = connection_element.find('id')
        if controlType is not None and str(controlType.text) == '6':
            # Now find all of the classname(s) in this specific connection element.
            for class_name in connection_element.findall('classes/class/classname'):
                audio[connectionID.text].append(class_name.text)
    return audio
```

Using `audio[connectionID.text] = class_name.text` will overwrite the value each time through the loop, dicts cannot have duplicate keys so using a list you can append and store all the values for each key .

If you want to print the key and values:

```
for k in audio:
    for val in audio[k]:
        print("{}:{}".format(k,val))
```

Or:

```
for k,vals in audio.iteritems():
    for val in vals:
        print("{}:{}".format(k,val))
```

Comment: OK, that seemed to work.  I am now getting multiple values per key.  But how does one iterate over this now? Previously when it was a dictionary I would use something like:  for id, classname in myDictionary.interitems():  print id, classname.  How will this change with the defaultdict?

Comment: just iterate over the dict itself, then for val in d[k]:print k,val, I added an example

Comment: Thank you, ive been trying to figure out why i cant use multiple same keys with different values, now i know.